# Firefox does not wait to Jquery.load() function

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, jquery-load

```
talkbox.load('/xxforum.php?webpage_id='+webpage_id , function() {
      talkbox.append('<a href="/forum/'+webpage_id+'/1" style="margin-left:40%">Go To Forum</a>');
}); 

  talkbox.removeClass("invisible").addClass("visible");
```

I have above code. After I load `xxforum.php` I append a `<a>` tag to end. After that I make talkbox visible.  However in Firefox it does not wait to append the `<a>` tag. It directly shows the box and then appends the `<a>` tag. Which is not right because my function inside the `$.load()` function.In google chrome everything works as I want. Anybody encountered something like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is load is `async` move it inside:

```
talkbox.load('/xxforum.php?webpage_id='+webpage_id , function() {
      talkbox.append('<a href="/forum/'+webpage_id+'/1" style="margin-left:40%">Go To Forum</a>');
  talkbox.removeClass("invisible").addClass("visible");
});
```